# How to use local variables in a Bash function

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a Bash script which will stop a repository of Docker containers, re-build them, and run some tests on them (using Pytest). To make the code DRY, I tried to define a function `wait_for_container` as follows:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)

docker-compose build

docker-compose up -d

function wait_for_container {
    local CONTAINER=$1
    local PORT=$2

    ADDR=$(docker inspect --format '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' $CONTAINER)

    until nc -z $CONTAINER $PORT
    do
        echo "Waiting for the $CONTAINER container..."
        sleep 0.5
    done
    echo "$CONTAINER listening at $ADDR:$PORT"
}

RETHINKDB_CONTAINER=ipercroncompose_rethinkdb_1
RETHINKDB_PORT=28015
wait_for_container $RETHINKDB_CONTAINER $RETHINKDB_PORT

RABBITMQ_CONTAINER=ipercroncompose_rabbitmq_1
RABBITMQ_PORT=5672
wait_for_container $RABBITMQ_CONTAINER $RABBITMQ_PORT

cd test
pytest
```

However, I find that this doesn't work: I repetitively get

```
nc: getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution
Waiting for the ipercroncompose_rethinkdb_1 container...
```

On the other hand, the following non-DRY script *does* work:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)

docker-compose build

docker-compose up -d

RETHINKDB_CONTAINER=ipercroncompose_rethinkdb_1
RETHINKDB_ADDR=$(docker inspect --format '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' $RETHINKDB_CONTAINER)
RETHINKDB_PORT=28015

until nc -z $RETHINKDB_ADDR $RETHINKDB_PORT
do
    echo "Waiting for the RethinkDB container..."
    sleep 0.5
done
echo "RethinkDB listening at ${RETHINKDB_ADDR}:${RETHINKDB_PORT}."

RABBITMQ_CONTAINER=ipercroncompose_rabbitmq_1
RABBITMQ_ADDR=$(docker inspect --format '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' $RABBITMQ_CONTAINER)
RABBITMQ_PORT=5672

until nc -z $RABBITMQ_ADDR $RABBITMQ_PORT
do
    echo "Waiting for the RabbitMQ container..."
    sleep 0.5
done
echo "RabbitMQ listening at ${RABBITMQ_ADDR}:${RABBITMQ_PORT}."

cd test
pytest
```

and echoes

```
RethinkDB listening at 172.18.0.2:28015.
Waiting for the RabbitMQ container...
Waiting for the RabbitMQ container...
Waiting for the RabbitMQ container...
Waiting for the RabbitMQ container...
Waiting for the RabbitMQ container...
Waiting for the RabbitMQ container...
Waiting for the RabbitMQ container...
Waiting for the RabbitMQ container...
Waiting for the RabbitMQ container...
Waiting for the RabbitMQ container...
Waiting for the RabbitMQ container...
Waiting for the RabbitMQ container...
Waiting for the RabbitMQ container...
Waiting for the RabbitMQ container...
Waiting for the RabbitMQ container...
Waiting for the RabbitMQ container...
Waiting for the RabbitMQ container...
Waiting for the RabbitMQ container...
Waiting for the RabbitMQ container...
Waiting for the RabbitMQ container...
Waiting for the RabbitMQ container...
Waiting for the RabbitMQ container...
Waiting for the RabbitMQ container...
Waiting for the RabbitMQ container...
Waiting for the RabbitMQ container...
Waiting for the RabbitMQ container...
Waiting for the RabbitMQ container...
Waiting for the RabbitMQ container...
RabbitMQ listening at 172.19.0.2:5672.
```

followed by the results of the Pytests. How can I improve the `wait_for_container` function to achieve the same effect?

Comment: I am not seeing anything wrong at a cursory glance (you should probably quote variable expansions, but your sample data does not seem problematic with unquoted expansions), and strangely the issue seems to be with the `nc` utility being called.  Could you add logging to your script so that you can see what the whole `nc` command actually looks like when executed?

Comment: By the way, using functions to avoid code duplication is the way to go and there is no reason it should not work, so take the time to work this out (it probably is just some small, hard-to-spot issue that may not be related to using a function at all).

Comment: `until nc -z $CONTAINER $PORT` ==> `until nc -z $ADDR $PORT`

Comment: GrishaLevit is right.  You should also make your `ADDR` variable local, by the way, because it is currently leaking to the calling context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [Grisha Levit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1072229/grisha-levit)'s and [Fred](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7422249/fred)'s comments, here is the adapted script:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d

function wait_for_container {
    local CONTAINER=$1
    local PORT=$2

    local ADDR=$(docker inspect --format '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' $CONTAINER)
    echo $ADDR

    until nc -z $ADDR $PORT
    do
        echo "Waiting for the $CONTAINER container..."
        sleep 0.5
    done
    echo "$CONTAINER listening at $ADDR:$PORT"
}

wait_for_container ipercroncompose_rethinkdb_1 28015
wait_for_container ipercroncompose_rabbitmq_1 5672

cd test
pytest
```

The problem was indeed that `netcat` requires an IP address as its first input, not a Docker container name. (I also made the `ADDR` variable local).

Comment: Just a general code practice, capitalized variables are meant to be  used only for  environment variables, lower case your local script variables for better readability.